# Delete master password authentification Dell Latitude e6500

Tags: dell-latitude

I have a friend who recently offered a Dell Latitude E6500 laptop but when I turn it on I come across this message. Can anyone help me with a generic password or any other solution?

[image: message error]

Comment: Is it a bios password?

Comment: I don't think so since I tried the cmos battery by removing it and putting it back after a while but nothing has changed

Comment: So ask your "friend" for the password ...

Comment: what an idea of ​​genius I hadn't thought of ... seriously he didn't! Besides, he is even surprised that I tell him that there is a password ... according to him, he never configured a password.

Comment: This is a boot password, and your friend set it, regardless what they say.